# Aligning Strings in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

so i have this string and all of the strings have different string length i have tried doing `padding` but it does not align correctly this is what i have so far

```
  Structure studentDetails

        Dim FirstName As String
        Dim SurName As String
        Dim marks As Integer
    End Structure

     Private Sub btnDetails_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDetails.Click

     Dim sd(3) as studentDetails 
     sd(0).FirstName = "Tom"
     sd(0).SurName = "jay"
     sd(0).marks = "0"

     sd(1).FirstName = "steven"
     sd(1).SurName = "crab"
     sd(1).marks = "20"

     sd(2).FirstName = "jack"
     sd(2).SurName = "thisislonglastname"
     sd(2).marks = "60"


     For I To 3

     label1.text =  label1.text & sd(I).FirstName.padright(10) & sd(I).SurName.padright(10) & sd(I).marks.ToString().padright(10) & Vbnewline

     Next
     End Sub
```

but my output gives an incorrect format i would like it to be displayed like this

```
 Tom     jay                      0
 Steven  crab                     20
 jack    thisislonglastname       60
```

How can i do this

Comment: What font are you using? If your textbox is not set to use a monospaced font, then the text won't line up because the width of each character varies in most fonts

Comment: Is there some reason it must be in a `label` versus one of the grid controls?

Comment: If you're willing to use a `RichTextBox` you can use the `SelectionTabs` property. Or using a `ListBox` see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/318600 I used that one back in VB6 even.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DataGridView`(obviously you are in Winforms).
Put values in different columns, remove borders between columns and rows - and you get same view you want to achive.

```
Private Sub btnDetails_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, 
                             ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDetails.Click

    Dim sd(3) As studentDetails 

    'Fill array with students values

    yourDataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = True; 'This is true by default
    yourDataGridView.ColumnHeadersVisible = False
    yourDataGridView.RowHeadersVisible = False
    yourDataGridView.CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.None

    yourDataGridView.DataSource = sd
End Sub
```

Be sure that `yourDataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns` set to `True` and columns will be generate automatically based on properties of your class